# Troubleshooting "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Tags: reactjs, node.js, authentication, jwt, access-token

I'm encountering an issue in my web application where I'm receiving the error message "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" in the browser console. This error occurs when trying to load a particular resource from the server.

Here's what I've already checked:

Verified that the URL for the resource is correct.
Checked the code, error and data used for any additional information about the internal server error.
Ensured that the server is running and accessible.
Verified that the server is properly configured to handle the requested resource.
Despite these checks, I'm still unable to resolve the issue. Could someone please provide guidance on further troubleshooting steps or potential causes for this error? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
[image: Error]
Data
[image: Data]

**Codes**
App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import RoomDetail from './components/dashboard/Rooms/RoomDetail';
import ListingBooking from './components/dashboard/Booking/BookingList';
import ListingRoom from './components/dashboard/Rooms/RoomsList';
import ListUsers from './components/dashboard/Customers/UsersList';
import Signin from './components/dashboard/Customers/Signin';
import Signup from './components/dashboard/Customers/Signup';
import ListRoom from './components/ListRoom';
import Dashboard from './components/dashboard/Dashboard';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [userType, setUserType] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkLoggedIn = async () => {
      try {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn');
        if (token) {
          // Validate the token on the server
          const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/accounts/signin', {
            token,
          });
          setIsLoggedIn(true);
          setUserType(response.data.user.role);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error checking login status:', error);
        console.log("Response ", await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/accounts/signin'))

      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    checkLoggedIn();
  }, []);

  const isAuthenticated = () => {
    return isLoggedIn && userType === 'admin';
  };

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={() => <h2>Home</h2>} />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/dashboard"
          render={() => (isAuthenticated() ? <Dashboard /> : <Redirect to="/signin" />)}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/dashboard/rooms/:roomId"
          render={() => (isAuthenticated() ? <RoomDetail /> : <Redirect to="/signin" />)}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/dashboard/rooms/"
          render={() => (isAuthenticated() ? <ListingRoom /> : <Redirect to="/signin" />)}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/dashboard/customers"
          render={() => (isAuthenticated() ? <ListUsers /> : <Redirect to="/signin" />)}
        />
        <Route exact path="/signin" component={Signin} />
        <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={ListRoom} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Signin code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'; // Import Redirect
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import axios from 'axios';

const Signin = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ emailOrUsername: '', password: '' });
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false); // Track authentication status

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/accounts/signin', formData);

      if (response.status === 200) {
        setIsLoggedIn(true); 
      } else {
        setError('An error occurred while signing in. Please try again later.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error signing in:', error);
      setError('An error occurred while signing in. Please try again later.');
    }
  };

  // Redirect if logged in
  if (isLoggedIn) {
    return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />;
  }

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
        Sign in
      </Typography>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <TextField
          variant="outlined"
          margin="normal"
          required
          fullWidth
          id="emailOrUsername"
          label="Email or Username"
          name="emailOrUsername"
          autoComplete="email"
          autoFocus
          value={formData.emailOrUsername}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <TextField
          variant="outlined"
          margin="normal"
          required
          fullWidth
          name="password"
          label="Password"
          type="password"
          id="password"
          autoComplete="current-password"
          value={formData.password}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <Button type="submit" fullWidth variant="contained" color="primary">
          Sign In
        </Button>
        {error && <Typography color="error">{error}</Typography>}
      </form>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Signin;
```

Account Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const accountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['admin', 'user'],
    required: true
  },
  user: {
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
  }
});

const Account = mongoose.model('Account', accountSchema);

module.exports = Account;
```

Account Route

```
const express = require("express");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const Account = require("../models/Account");
const router = express.Router();

// Route to get all accounts
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Find all accounts
    const accounts = await Account.find();

    res.status(200).json({ accounts });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching accounts:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
});

// Route to create a new account
router.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { user, username, email, password, role } = req.body;

    // Check if the email is already registered
    const existingAccount = await Account.findOne({ email });
    if (existingAccount) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Email is already registered" });
    }

    // Hash the password
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

    // Create the new user
    const newAccount = await Account.create({
      user,
      username,
      password: hashedPassword,
      role,
    });

    res
      .status(201)
      .json({ message: "Account created successfully", user: newAccount });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error creating account:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
});

// Route to get account by ID
router.get("/:_id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { accountId } = req.params;

    // Find account by ID and populate the user field
    const account = await Account.findById(accountId).populate("user");

    if (!account) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Account not found" });
    }

    // Return the account details
    res.status(200).json({ account });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching account:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
});

// Route to signin
router.post("/signin", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    // Check if the email is registered
    const user = await Account.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Account not found" });
    }

    // Compare passwords
    const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!isPasswordValid) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid credentials" });
    }

    const secretKey = process.env.JWT_SECRET;

    // Sign JWT token
    const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, secretKey, {
      expiresIn: "1h",
    });

    res.status(200).json({ message: "Signin successful", token });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error signing in:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
});


module.exports = router;
```